# how to get the path of server's folder inside Java program (J2EE + JSTL)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I wanted to read contents of Excel files in my web-based project (J2EE-JSP+Servlets) which are located inside the web server's folder.

I have made a java file, which i will call through a JSP page using JSTL library, but I need to get the path of the Excel sheet in the Java file, so I can read the contents.

How can I get the path to the current Java file and so the Excel file?

Also, I will be reading the contents of the Excel file through POI library. I was able to do this in J2SE development, but is it possible here?

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
    try {
        fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("**some path here of sheet**"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    HSSFWorkbook wb = null;
    try {
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFRow row;
    HSSFCell cell1,cell2,cell3; 

    int rows; // No of rows, stores the no. of rows for an excel sheet
    int cols; // No of columns, stores the no. of columns for an excel sheet

    rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    cols = 5;

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        row = sheet.getRow(r);

        if(row != null) {
            cell1 = row.getCell(1);
            cell2 = row.getCell(2);
            cell3 = row.getCell(4);

            //System.out.println(cell1.getStringCellValue()+" "+cell2.getStringCellValue()+" "+cell3.getStringCellValue());                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the code you pasted inside a servlet's method? If not, exactly how are you calling the code from the JSP?

Comment: I am calling this code from jsp using jstl library.. <% ReadExcel readExcel = new ReadExcel(); %>.. I am not able to configure the bean property..  <jsp:useBean id="excelBean" scope="request" class="some.ExcelBean" >
    <jsp:setProperty name="physicalPath" value="<%= application.getRealPath("/") %>" />
</jsp:useBean>

Answer (score 4):

You can ask servlet context to translate relative to real path:

```
context.getRealPath("/");
```

If you java class is servlet, you can probably do something like

```
getServletConfig().getServletContext();
```

otherwise, jsp page is a servlet, so you can pass it from there.

Finally, you can pick it up once when you start your app:

```
public class AppStartup implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
        // remember it in some static class for future use
    }
}
```

Having said all this, it's probably better to make a servlet that has his servlet context, resolve path, and call your class with resolved path to a file, then finally forward request to a jsp page to display results.

Comment: how can i do this in my java file,, do i need to import some library to this.. and it is not a servlet basically, i have not used any library for servlet in this file.. It is just a java file.. which i have created,, and i will call this file through JSP-JSTL library..

Comment: sir, can you give me the complete coding of this, with necessary libraries which i need to import, with some explanation.. as i am new to servlets,, and i have no idea, what's your program doing.. and how i can incorporate that in my java code..

Comment: ok, can you give me some online tutorial wherein i can read all those things which you have mentioned in your program..

Answer (score 1):

In a basic JSP/Servlet app you'd have a backing servlet which will do almost all the logic in your program, *push* the model into a request and then redirect the user to a JSP page that will *pull* the model from the request and will only format it (by using JSTL if you want). If your method needs to perform some kind of processing using the Excel file it should be inside a class extending javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet this way you could access the ServletContext and its method

```
String physicalFolder = getContext().getRealPath("/");
```

If you don't want to follow this approach and want to still JSTL (I guess you're using *<jsp:useBean />* tag) you may initialize a bean property setting the physical folder of your webapp using something like this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="excelBean" scope="request" class="yourpackage.YourClass" >
    <jsp:setProperty name="physicalPath" value="<%= application.getRealPath("/") %>" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

Comment: POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
        try {
            fs = new POIFSFileSystem(getClass().getResourceAsStream("path of excel file here"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 


what should i write here,, inorder to recieve the path from jsp file..

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /admin/upload-excel-files_action.jsp(12,0) The value for the useBean class attribute yourpackage.YourClass is invalid. I have put the appropriately yourpackage and yourclass but it is showing this error. please review...

Comment: yourpackage and YourClass is an example if your class has no package and it's called ReadExcel you should've put just "ReadExcel"..... hmmm leaving here

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong approach.

You should be reading that file by putting it in WEB-INF/classes and using getResourceAsStream to get the InputStream from the context path using the file name.

Try looking at [this](http://www.xyzws.com/servletfaq/how-to-use-servletcontextgetresourceasstreamjavalangstring-path/18) example.

Comment: can you give me a small example sir,, how to read the excel file using getResourceAsStream..

Comment: Yes, I wrote my response before loading his answer.  Martin has the straight dope for you.

Comment: Sir, i am not able to understand ur codes.. plz either provide any online tutorial to my problm or plz give some detailed explanation..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect if you're looking for the local filesystem path on the server it may not be possible.  Although some web application servers (notably Tomcat, I think) do have a folder containing all of your app's files, there are others that run apps directly from a compressed WAR file.  In this case there may not be a path to your Excel file as it would be inside an archive.

One possible way around this that's independent of the application server you're running on would be to package the Excel file inside one of the JARs in `WEB-INF/lib`, and then read it using

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/class/path/to/file.xls")
```

instead of

```
new FileInputStream("/local/filesystem/path/file.xls")
```

When using getResourceAsStream("...") you need to supply a class path, rather than a filesystem path.  So, if you packaged the Excel file inside a JAR, in a package called `com.yourcompany.files`, you'd need to use

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/yourcompany/files/file.xls")
```

Comment: fs = new POIFSFileSystem(getClass().getResourceAsStream("usr/local/shared/tomcat/localhost/webapps/foldername/filename.xls"));

I have used this path, this is also return null values exception..
what path i need to insert in getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/excel/file/inside/jar/file.xls") so that i can read the file located on servers folder

Answer (score 0):

I second duffymo and Martin McNulty, you must use getResourceAsStream and put your Excel file, here it goes the example:

Your webapp structure is something like this, right?

```
- Application Root
 |
 +- WEB-INF
     |
     +- classes/  <--- This is added to CLASSPATH
     |
     +- lib/      <--- Its contents are added to CLASSPATH
     |
     +- web.xml
```

In this structure your application classpath is conformed by the JAR files located into *lib* folder and the *classes* folder. When you compile using an IDE the files located in your source folder are compiled and the *.class* files are copied in the *classes* folder, if the files are not Java files they're just copied in the folder, but still are in the classpath.

So, being briefly... **You can add not-class files in the classpath, like your Excel file** and organise it into packages just like it'd be a class.

If you put the Excel file in the classpath you'll have the advantage that the file can be accessed independently of your JAR file or WAR file location, just by knowing its location in the classpath.

The method *Class.getResourceAsStream(String path)* provides you access to files into the classpath, just pass the path replacing the dots by slashes, for example:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/yourpackage/YourExcelFile.xsl");
```

will provide you an InputStream of the file *YourExcelFile.xsl* that is inside the package *yourpackage*.

I tried my best to explain you this but if you have doubts you can check the [method documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).