# root path on java server from java class?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, relative-path

I made a java program to find hash values to all files of my web project in java so that I can find possibly (altered /added/hacked) files.
When I run this class directory.java, I am able to find hash values of files like this

```
\web\WEB-INF  ----- checking...OK
                  ajax-loader.gif -hash--437179c0b495121af68bdd64f797e02b
.\web\ajax-loader.gif--437179c0b495121af68bdd64f797e02b--Fri Dec 07 11:26:35 IST 2012
                  display.jsp -hash--b45f8db4489e42ecf3853a0c3cfab7a8
.\web\display.jsp--b45f8db4489e42ecf3853a0c3cfab7a8--Wed Dec 05 09:22:12 IST 2012
                  index.jsp -hash--d76170f1f30914ecc32fa81a0d7aa728
.\web\index.jsp--d76170f1f30914ecc32fa81a0d7aa728--Tue Nov 20 18:06:59 IST 2012
                  jssdkouth2.html -hash--31044821b876692909fd261152d2d102
.\web\jssdkouth2.html--31044821b876692909fd261152d2d102--Mon Dec 31 12:15:55 IST 2012
                  like.jpg -hash--c0c82ea9bc245ed09d2dd6ed38db5bb0
.\web\like.jpg--c0c82ea9bc245ed09d2dd6ed38db5bb0--Tue Dec 04 14:33:07 IST 2012
                  META-INF
.\web\META-INF\context.xml  ----- checking...OK
                        context.xml -hash--27a8469aef212e73798e265993ced40a
.\web\META-INF\context.xml--27a8469aef212e73798e265993ced40a--Tue Nov 20 18:06:56 IST 2012
                  newhtml1.html -hash--7b8a39efa9be4ad7de50759ce2ab25af
```

But when I run it from servlet I got hash values of files like this

```
    bootstrap.jar -hash--fea2494f41dd54fc0d693b01745c03d0
.\bootstrap.jar--fea2494f41dd54fc0d693b01745c03d0--Sun Nov 11 20:36:10 IST 2012
status for path=NEW
path found in db 
            catalina-tasks.xml -hash--3762f67ebfb0ac7e4c707a5b9f103f92
.\catalina-tasks.xml--3762f67ebfb0ac7e4c707a5b9f103f92--Thu Mar 10 15:44:44 IST 2011
status for path=NEW
path found in db 
            catalina.bat -hash--3fbace7fc74faf47844efb293c5d606b
.\catalina.bat--3fbace7fc74faf47844efb293c5d606b--Thu Mar 10 15:44:44 IST 2011
```

I tried passing starting path as below but neither worked

```
 String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
  String workingDir2=".";
```

So how to find path on server from java file? I don't want to pass path from servlet, as I will modify this to automatically generate report at midnight as email results.
Also what is the best way to schedule this program to run at midnight everyday?

Comment: "Also what is the best way to schedule this program to run at midnight everyday." - this is a completely different question than the rest of your question. (One not appropriate for SO either because it's better answered by Google.) Don't combine multiple questions into one.

Comment: Is this you are looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918396/how-to-get-the-path-of-servers-folder-inside-java-program-j2ee-jstl

Answer (score 1):

This is quite common, [I think this wud help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918396/how-to-get-the-path-of-servers-folder-inside-java-program-j2ee-jstl)

Regarding your second requirement, I think [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-schedule/index.html) explains it all!